# How to make a repeating background on my site?

Tags: html, css, background, web

My site, http://kunal.vr.lt has a background of 1920x1080, but it doesn't repeat, and on mobile browsers, it just shows a white empty space under the picture. How would I go about making the background consistent?
The index is linked to CSS file, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Please change this From your css it reslove your issue

```
body {
background-image: url("1886508.jpg");
/* background-repeat: no-repeat; Remove it*/
background-size: 1920px 1080px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

```
body {
   background-image: url("1886508.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   /*background-size: 1920px 1080px;*/
   background-size: cover;
}
```